# How to set a specific PlotStyle option for all curves without changing default colors?

Tags: plotting, color

I have a 3D plot of dozens of random curves which have different colors by default.  I want to keep the default colors but then I need all the curves to get a `Thick` style. If I use the option `PlotStyle -> Thick`, then all curves are turned to black.  I know this should be very basic, but I don't get it!

Here's a MWE to show the issue:

```
vec[t_, x_, y_, z_] := {x t, y t, z t}

x0[n_] := RandomReal[{-10, 10}]
y0[n_] := RandomReal[{-10, 10}]
z0[n_] := RandomReal[{-10, 10}]

vectors[t_] := Table[vec[t, x0[n], y0[n], z0[n]], {n, 1, 10}]

randVectors = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@vectors[t], {t, -30, 30}, PlotStyle -> {Thick}];

Show[
 randVectors,
 PlotRange -> Automatic,
 Axes -> None,
 BoxStyle -> Thick,
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
 ImageSize -> {500, 500},
 Background -> Black
 ]
```

The option `PlotStyle -> {Thick}` is causing the issue.  So how can I have a thick style for all curves, and yet still get various colors for them?  I need the default colors palette for the curves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
    vec[t_, x_, y_, z_] := {x t, y t, z t}

x0[n_] := RandomReal[{-10, 10}]
y0[n_] := RandomReal[{-10, 10}]
z0[n_] := RandomReal[{-10, 10}]

vectors[t_] := Table[vec[t, x0[n], y0[n], z0[n]], {n, 1, 10}];

styles = Table[{Hue[0.1*n], Thickness[0.005]}, {n, 1, 10}];

randVectors = 
 ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@vectors[t], {t, -30, 30}, 
  PlotStyle -> styles, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> None]

Show[randVectors, PlotRange -> Automatic, SphericalRegion -> True, 
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}, ImageSize -> {500, 500}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: This is a great one.  Love it!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I've found the solution:  Just use `BaseStyle -> Thick`, instead of `PlotStyle -> Thick`.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the generation of vectors

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

vec[t_, x_, y_, z_] := {x t, y t, z t}

SeedRandom[1234];
xyz = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10, 3}];

randVectors = ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[vec[t, ##] & @@@ xyz], {t, -30, 30},
   PlotStyle -> Thick];

Show[randVectors,
 Axes -> None,
 BoxStyle -> Thick,
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
 ImageSize -> {500, 500},
 Background -> Black]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to remove the thickness specifications from each line that were generated by `ParametricPlot3D` (as well as the annotations that you may not need), and add yours:

```
Show[
 randVectors /. 
  Annotation[{color_, ___, l : _Line}, ___] :> {color, Thickness[0.02], l},

 Boxed -> False,(*instead of BoxStyle -> Thick*)
 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, Axes -> None,
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
 ImageSize -> {500, 500},
 Background -> Black
]
```

I would also recommend using `Boxed -> False` to get rid of the encompassing box, which was showing on top of some of your lines as a black "blot" in your plot.

Comment: I need the box, in my full code, to help visualization on a black background.